# Trying to install Linux alongside a long-standing Windows installation: Unallocated space not recognized by the installer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I have shrunk the partition on my secondary drive (which doesn't have Windows on it) and Disk Management in Windows says I have ~400GB of 'unallocated' space. Yet according to the installer in Debian, Ubuntu, whatever I try, the drive doesn't have a 600/400 partitioning, it has a single 1TB partition.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows system tool for this is knows to show false information, especially when not exclusively Microsoft partitions are used. Just use GParted under Ubuntu. But make sure to operate on the right device when using GParted. You can choose the device in the top right.

Since you're new to this page: Please press the tick on the left it this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gparted when booting live from a USB/CD. If you do not have Gparted open a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

This should give you a better idea of what is happening with your partitions. Do this first then go to Install Debian from the Live session.

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue with any changes to your hard disk, you should create a complete backup of your Windows installation.

Do you know, if your hard d disk uses GPT or MBR structure? A GPT structure should also Containern a fake MBR. Maybe these two are not consistent.

Comment: Sadly I got too annoyed and just nuked my E: drive for Debian, which previously had junk, steam games, programs not wanted on the SSD, etc.